# write nested json in python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, json

I am having a problem while trying to build a JSON response from my server.

I want to get a JSON object that contains other JSON objects which I get as a result from SQL query so I would be able to send the containing JSON via my websocket server

Until now I tried something like this:

```
    def screenColor(self,ne_Lat, ne_Lng, sw_lat, sw_Lng):
    data={}
    allData=[]
    for rec in self.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM squares WHERE ((lat BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (long BETWEEN ? AND ?)) ''',(sw_lat, ne_Lat, sw_Lng, ne_Lng)):
          data['color']=rec[3]
          data['lat']=rec[1]
          data['lng']=rec[2]
          json_data=json.dumps(data)
          allData.append(json_data)
    return allData
```

and when I print the returned value i get:

```
['{"color": 85, "lat": 31.776879500000156, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.778179500000157, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.779479500000157, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.780779500000158, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.782079500000158, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.78337950000016, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 26, "lat": 31.78467950000016, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 28, "lat": 31.78597950000016, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.78727950000016, "lng": 35.21187200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.776879500000156, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 28, "lat": 31.778179500000157, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.779479500000157, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 26, "lat": 31.780779500000158, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 26, "lat": 31.782079500000158, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 26, "lat": 31.78337950000016, "lng": 35.21367200000153}', '{"color": 85, "lat": 31.78467950000016, "lng": 35.21367200000153}
```

Is there is a way to get this array as a JSON object? Is that already a JSON object?

Thank you very much!

Comment: make nested object and json.dumps()

Comment: Currently you have a list of strings (in JSON format), you just have to add the data dicts (as dicts, not as JSON) to allData and then execute json.dumps (allData) at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
def screenColor(self,ne_Lat, ne_Lng, sw_lat, sw_Lng):

    allData=[]
    for rec in self.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM squares WHERE ((lat BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (long BETWEEN ? AND ?)) ''',(sw_lat, ne_Lat, sw_Lng, ne_Lng)):
          data = {}
          data['color']=rec[3]
          data['lat']=rec[1]
          data['lng']=rec[2]

          allData.append(data)
    return json.dumps(allData)
```

Otherwise, if you define your dictionary `data` outside the loop, it will be overwritten at every iteration I guess...